# Is This Really What I Think This is?

Tags: riddle

> You must all be wondering, what I am
>
> Well let me give you some help to figure it out
>
> Placed within the inside of an object
>
> Is where you'll be able to find me
>
> Bright red is my colour
>
> With the addition of a rotated triangle on me
>
> People worldwide use me daily
>
> I can help you see literally anything in this world
>
> From the greatest of all like the Seven Wonders of The World
>
> To the most obscure places on Earth
>
> Even the latest news can be found in me
>
> Now tell me, what the hell am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you

> YouTube?

Placed within the inside of an object

> I don't really get this

But the rest matches:

> people use YouTube every day to look at things, and the logo for YouTube is a bright red rectangle with a triangle.

Comment: Yes the answer is right! Well youtube is an app and it is usually inside an electronic device, like a phone @Eutherpy